# Inheritance with possible template failure

Tags: c++, c++11

An error in a method that relies on template expansion only gives a compiler error when the method is explicitly called. Though when that method is marked as virtual, it produces a compiler error whether or not it is actually called. Is there anything in the C++ standard that explains why marking these methods as virtual causes a compiler error?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <class T_>
class Foo
{
protected:
    T_ data;
public:
    Foo(const T_& x) : data(x) { }

    Foo(T_&& x) : data(std::move(x)) { }

    // comment these two lines out and it works fine.
    virtual void test(T_& x) = 0;
    virtual void test(T_&& x) = 0;
};

template <class T_>
class Bar : public Foo<T_>
{
public:
    using Foo<T_>::Foo;

    void test(T_& x)
    {
        std::cout << "test(&)" << std::endl;
        x = this->data;
    }

    void test(T_&& x)
    {
        std::cout << "test(&&)" << std::endl;
        x = std::move(this->data);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar<std::unique_ptr<int>> x(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overriders of `virtual` functions are always odr-used - that is, their definition must be present, whether they are explicitly used in a translation unit or not.
 Overriders of `virtual` functions are themselves `virtual` ([class.virtual]/2) and all `virtual` functions must be defined ([basic.def.odr]/3 and 4).

Now the question is whether the `test` overloads in the derived class are actually instantiated.
For templates, the standard mandates that

> Unless a member of a class template […] has been
>   explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization
>   of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist;

For virtual functions one might argue that their presence is enough to require a definition. However, the standard doesn't tie itself down and leaves the decision to the implementation, [temp.inst]/11:

> It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly
>   instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the
>   virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.

Comment: Also relevant is [temp.inst]/p11 - "An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate [...] a non-virtual member function [...] of a class template that does not require instantiation. It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated."

Comment: The declarations *are* instantiated when the class template is instantiated. The definitions *aren't*, by default ([temp.inst]/p1). The general rule is that "the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist" ([temp.inst]/p2). Whether being *odr-used* counts as such a context is unclear. Regardless, [temp.inst]/p11 gives the compiler leeway to instantiate a virtual member function that would not otherwise be instantiated.

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, I just found the same quote. I was unclear about when a requirement exists, but that seems to be a vagueness of the standard itself.

Answer (score 0):

Making it virtual is forcing instantiation. I get the same error with the following test code after commenting out the virtual function in the base class:

```
int main()
{
    Bar<std::unique_ptr<int>> x(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)));
    x.test(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(99)));
    std::unique_ptr<int> pi;
    x.test(pi);
    std::cout << "test returned " << *pi << std::endl;
}
```

The version taking an reference can't be instantiated as `std::unique_ptr` is not assignable.